# python list append is not working in python evaluate reverse polish notation

Tags: python, list, append, postfix-notation

```
class Solution:
    def evalRPN(self, tokens: List[str]) -> int:
        surya = []
        x = 0
        y = 0
        res = 0
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            if tokens[i].isnumeric():
                surya.append(int(tokens[i]))
            
            else:
                y = surya.pop()
                x = surya.pop()
                if(tokens[i] == "*"):
                    res = x*y
                elif(tokens[i] == "/"):
                    res = x/y
                elif(tokens[i] == "+"):
                    res = x+y
                else:
                    res = x-y
        
        return res
```

Input: tokens = ["2","1","+","3","*"]
Output: 9

My Output:

IndexError: pop from empty list

```
x = surya.pop()
Line 14 in evalRPN (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().evalRPN(param_1)
Line 43 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 54 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

The output is showing like above, The code seems ok, but it is not working... It is a question from leet code link to the image of the question is attached

Comment: There are some issues with your code, to understand the problem I recommend printing the content of `surya` after each `append` and `pop`. The main issue here is that you try to `pop` twice when the list only contains a single element.

Comment: I printed the content -- both the list and the tokens[i] -- list is empty but tokens[i] is being printed

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/ this is the question I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

When you process an operation you should put your result on `surya`, otherwise when you find the next operator you will have only one operand to process.
Btw it also means you don't need the `res` variable, the final result will be the only remaining value in `surya`